# Where is this street-art in Buenos Aires?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this, buenos-aires

[image]
The account replied: "The place is called 'Paseo de la Costa' in Vicente Lopez. Its very close to a big supermarket named 'Carrefour', located at Avenida Libertador 215. You should cross the supermarket and turn right into a way that leads to the river. You will see the streetart, is huge. Good luck!"

I tried to find it in google streetview but can't find the wall. Any one has idea of it still exists and where it is exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wall itself is visible on [Street View](https://www.google.cz/maps/@-34.5307944,-58.4675403,3a,75y,151.12h,83.3t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sAQXdVulWdBMB4iyAA_zK_g!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1):

[image]

Graffiti usually lasts for a few months at most, so it's anyone's guess if it will still be there by the time you arrive.